# Extracting the input records from feature file(bdd format) and convert it into a dictionary/lists/csv/json in python

Tags: python, python-behave

> Scenario: some scenario
>
> Given a set of specific users
>
> | name | department |
>
> | Barry | Beer Cans |
>
> | Pudey | Silly Walks |
>
> | Two-Lumps | Silly Walks |
>
> When we count the number of people in each department
>
> Then we will find two people in "Silly Walks"
>
> But we will find one person in "Beer Cans"

I need to convert the above feature file in python in such a way that I get the below output:

names= ['Barry','Pudey','Two-Lumps']

department =['Beer Cans','Silly Walks','Silly Walks']

dict = {"Name": names, "Department": deartment}

It would be fine if it could be converted to a data frame too.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data through `context.table`. In your `.py` file, in the `@given` function, add:

```
names=[]
departments=[]
for row in context.table:
    names.append(row['name'])
    departments.append(row['department'])
#add lists to a dictionary etc.
```

For a more generic approach, you could do the following instead of the code above:

```
my_dict={
    heading: [row[heading] for row in context.table] for heading in context.table.headings
}
```

**Pros:** dynamic, you can use this code for datasets much larger than the 2 lists in your example
**Cons:** less readable if you're new to Python